# Format specifier %u used with sprintf is creating crash

Tags: c, format-specifiers

When I used `%u` in `sprintf()` application gets crashed, it's working fine with `%d`

See the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    unsigned char dAddr[4];
    unsigned char sMask[4];
    unsigned char nHop[4];
    memset(dAddr,0,sizeof(dAddr));
    memset(sMask,0,sizeof(sMask));
    memset(nHop,0,sizeof(nHop));
    unsigned int u4IpDAddr = 0x01020304;
    unsigned int u4IpSNetMask = 0xffff01ff;
    unsigned int u4NHopGt = 0x01020304;
    char *dip = (char *)&u4IpDAddr;
    char *smk = (char *)&u4IpSNetMask;
    char *nhp = (char *)&u4NHopGt;
    sprintf(dAddr, "%u.%u.%u.%u", dip[3], dip[2], dip[1], dip[0]);  //if I used %d.%d.%d.%d its working fine
    sprintf(sMask, "%u.%u.%u.%u", smk[3], smk[2], smk[1], smk[0]); //if I used %d.%d.%d.%d its working fine
    sprintf(nHop, "%u.%u.%u.%u", nhp[3], nhp[2], nhp[1], nhp[0]); //if I used %d.%d.%d.%d its working fine
    printf("SAM: func %s line %d IpDAddr %s Mask %s NHop %s\n",__func__,__LINE__,dAddr,sMask,nHop);
}
```

when I declared a pointer's with following manner its working fine for `%u.%u.%u.%u` format

```
unsigned char *dip = (unsigned char *)&u4IpDAddr;
unsigned char *smk = (unsigned char *)&u4IpSNetMask;
unsigned char *nhp = (unsigned char *)&u4NHopGt;
```

Can any one explain what is happening when I used `char` pointers?

Comment: This is crazy code. What in the world are you trying to do?

Comment: Sourav already gave the only real answer there is.  You are overrunning the bounds of your arrays (both ways) and the results are undefined.  However, depending on your data and the signedness of default `char` in your environment, it may be that you are overrunning your arrays *more* when you use plain `char` pointers, as a result of reinterpretation of a negative signed number (a `char` promoted to `int`) as an unsigned one.  That could explain why the observed (undefined) results differ.

Comment: Using `%u` with `smk` will cause undefined behaviour. `%u` is only for printing unsigned ints (or ints with non-negative values), but some of `smk`'s values are negative chars.

Comment: @sourav, if it so, how its working fine when we used unsigned char *smk = (unsigned char *)&u4IpSNetMask;

Answer (score 9):

In your case

```
unsigned char dAddr[4];
unsigned char sMask[4];
unsigned char nHop[4];
```

are not sufficient to hold the *lexicographical* output.

When you're using those arrays as the destination string in `sprintf()`, essentially, you're overrunning the allocated memory, creating  [undefined behaviour](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

You need to allocate more memory to use those arrays as the destination of `sprintf()`.

Answer (score 1):

If `char` is signed on your platform, then `char` value that you "hack out" of your `u4IpSNetMask` are more than likely to be negative, since you have bytes that begin with `0xF...` in `u4IpSNetMask`. When you send such `char` values to `sprintf` they get converted to negative `int` values and then reinterpreted as `unsigned` values by your `%u` specifier. The behavior is actually undefined - it is illegal to `sprintf` negative `int` values with `%u`. However, in practice you usually end up with a huge positive values that require many characters to represent. These representations easily overflow your destination buffers, destroy the program stack and cause your program to crash.

You can see for yourself what your `sprintf` calls generate on a typical platform: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6aec03cfdf28f8b2

The middle `sprintf` produces `4294967295.4294967295.1.4294967295`. And you expected this monster to fit into buffer `sMask` of only 4 characters long?

Moreover, the same kind of overflow happens with `%d` as well, but the string representation produced by `%d` is shorter (`-1` in place of `4294967295`) an the damage is smaller, which is probably why the program sort of limps to the end without crashing. But that does not change the fact that string `1.2.3.4` requires a char buffer of at least 8 characters long. You provided only 4.

In other words, your program is as broken with `%d` as it is broken with `%u`. If it did not crash with `%d`, it is just out of random luck.